# UIButtons not working in Scroll View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, scrollview

I have a `Scroll View` with a View (content view) inside of it. I've added two buttons to test. The `Scroll View` scrolls fine but the buttons within the content view are not clickable. I've seen plenty of posts saying this issue happens when they programmatically add `UIButtons` to the View, but I am not doing this. Here is my exact process:

1. Drag the Scroll View onto the main view. Add 4 constraints
2. Drag the Content View onto the Scroll View. Add 4 constraints.
3. Add 2 Buttons (one high and one low to test scrolling) to the Content View.

This is all I am doing, no code at this point. Is there anything else I have to do to allow the buttons to be clicked? Here is a screenshot of my xib:

[image]

**Update:**

When hooking the button up to a simple IBAction and logging a message, it turns out it IS being pushed and working properly. However, when the button is pushed, the button isn't changing colors like it should (its "pressed" state is not appearing). Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you have the buttons hooked up to IBActions?

Comment: @BenKane it seems like when I hook it up to IBAction it does call that function, however the button does not appear to be pushed (it doesn't change color as the other buttons do in my app) Any reason for this? Will update OP with this info

Comment: check if button type is System

Comment: @ChikabuZ it is System

Comment: If I click and hold, it changes states, but not if I click regularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First make the button to custom type
- Select button from storyboard then on **right attributed inspector** change its "state config" to whatever you need like **Highlighted, selected, Disabled** and default and choose the colour for each state.
- Now you can see the colour change on that button.

Answer (score 1):

A UIScrollView first needs to know whether or not you are going to *scroll* before letting the touch pass to its child views.  If you want the child views to get the touch immediately, set the UIScrollView's `delaysContentTouches` to `NO`.